# Vertical push doesn't let the object fall down instantly [UNITY]

Tags: unity, physics, rigidbody, rigid-body-dynamics, collider

An object (Wall) is continuously moving forward on the X axis with a simple script:

```
public float speed = .2f;
void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.Translate(speed, 0, 0);
}
```

It is pushing an other object (Penguin), which is affected by gravity. It can "jump" too, with a script of:

```
public void Jump()
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 1.15f, transform.position.z);
}
```

When jumping, over a certain value of speed, like **0.2f**, [the Penguin is not falling to the ground](https://vimeo.com/385443783) until it reaches a velocity Vector of around **(0.0, -10.0f, 0.0)**.

Setting the speed to **0.02f** makes it instantly fall.

How can I achieve the same result with higher speed value?

I attached the setup of the two object in inspector:[image]

Comment: If you want these objects to interact physically, you should treat the transform component as off-limits and move them purely with rigidbody methods.

Comment: In this case, `MovePosition` for the wall, and `AddForce` or `velocity` for the penguin

Comment: @LouisGarczynski could you add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @LuisGarczynski could you check this topic too please? https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/178484/pushing-an-object-on-other-colliders-makes-the-pusher-object-go-through-unity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move a rigidbody, there's a few different tools:

---

If it is not kinematic, use rigidbody.velocity or rigidbody.AddForce. For example

```
rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * playerSpeed;
```

---

If it is kinematic, use MovePosition:

```
rigidbody.MovePosition(rigidbody.position + Vector3.forward * (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * playerSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
```

---

If you use a CharacterController, use [Move](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html) or SimpleMove.

```
controller.Move(Vector3.forward * (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
```

---

Only use rigidbody.position if you want to teleport your rigidbody instead of moving it continuously.

Only use transform.position if you don't have a rigidbody, or want to teleport a character controller.

---

Rotations follow nearly the exact same rules. Scaling is however more complicated, and should be avoided for rigidbodies.